# New-ADUser and SAMAccountName limit

Tags: powershell

I've put together a script that creates accounts in AD and assigns a bunch of info including group membership based on input from a CSV. I use the .Substring method to create a temporary password using parts of the new hire's name. But when I try to set the SamAccountName using the .Substring method to grab the first 20 characters of the username with the same syntax as when I set the password, I'm treated to errors.

Within the same New-ADUser command, why does the below set the password as the first character of their FirstName followed by the first character of their LastName just like I would expect

> -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring($Firstname.Substring(0,1)+$Lastname.Substring(0,1))
> -AsPlainText -Force)

While the below does not set the SamAccountName as the first 20 characters of the Username? I get errors no matter how I've tried to do it.

> -SamAccountName ($Username.Substring(0,20))

Error below:

> Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length
> must refer to a location within the string.Parameter name: length"At
> C:\Create_AD_Users.ps1:28 char:7+
> New-ADUser `+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          :
> NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException    +
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: What's the error you get? Please add it completely to your question formatted as code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that error means that the string you were trying to slice is not long enuf to fit the requirements. it seems to be shorter than 20 chars. use regex instead OR use something that will grab UP TO the limit instead of trying to grab ALL the limit of something that is shorter than the limit. [*grin*]

Comment: Ah, so I need to check and see if the username is longer than 20 character, and only do the .Substring(0,20) if it is! Thanks, I'm betting that will solve it.

Comment: You will want to check the length even if it's shorter. You're basically trying to access something that isn't there in some cases if a username is shorter than others.

Comment: @KatMelendez-DeClue - yep, that is one way. i prefer to use something that will grab UP to the limit. for instance, this >>> `'123456789a123456789b123456789c' -replace '^(.{0,20}).*$', '$1'` <<< will give you `123456789a123456789b` and the same regex pattern with a 9 char string gives `123456789`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That bit of regex solved my issue and the advice will come in handy again I'm sure. I just got here today, is there some way I can mark your comment as the answer, or as helpful?

Comment: @KatMelendez-DeClue - comments are just that - comments. i will create an Answer and you can mark that if you wish. in any case, i am glad that you got things working as desired! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

here's a demo of what i meant by using regex to grab UP TO the limit instead of trying to grab ALL the limit.

what the code does ...

- creates an array of strings to work with
  just use your own when you get ready to do this for real.
- sets the max number of chars to capture
- iterates thru the collection of strings
- shows the original string
- uses regex to capture *up to* `$MaxChars` from the string
  if you want details on the exact working of the regex pattern, please go to ...
  regex101: build, test, and debug regex
  == https://regex101.com/
  the box in the upper right will explain the meaning of any regex pattern you put into the box in the upper center.
- displays that result
- draws a divider that is 20 chars long

the code ...

```
#region >>> make some strings to work on
# the below strings are 29, 30, 20, and 10 chars long
$InStuff = @'
Abcdefghi_Bcdefghij_Cdefghijk
123456789_123456789_123456789_
Qwertyuio_Asdfghjkl_
123456789_
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> make some strings to work on

$MaxChars = 17

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $IS_Item
    $IS_Item -replace "^(.{0,$MaxChars}).*$", '$1'
    # yes, you can multiply strings [*grin*] 
    '=' * 20
    }
```

output ...

```
Abcdefghi_Bcdefghij_Cdefghijk
Abcdefghi_Bcdefgh
====================
123456789_123456789_123456789_
123456789_1234567
====================
Qwertyuio_Asdfghjkl_
Qwertyuio_Asdfghj
====================
123456789_
123456789_
====================
```